# From Munich to Berlin, 6 hours in Dresden or Nuremberg or Bamberg or Leipzig?

Tags: germany, berlin, munich, leipzig, nuremberg

I am taking train from Munich to Berlin, and want to stop somewhere in the middle for about 6 hours (have lunch, visit one museum/tourist spot and then casually stroll around).  I am wondering which of the 4 is better fit?

I personally want to visit Dresden as it seems to be different from Munich and Berlin.  My itinerary also includes Rotherberg as a day trip from Munich.

Dresden 
Nuremberg 
Bamberg 
Leipzig?

Comment: Just to make sure: Dresden is almost surely not on the way from Munich to Berlin (the other three are) but a detour of ~3 hours.

Comment: Yes I understand, however Munich to Dresden then Dresden to Berlin is about 8 hours total.  Munich straight to Berlin is about 6.5 hours, so I consider it kind of "on the way".

Comment: Would you accept an answer that recommended a different city  than the three you gave?  Geographically half-way between Munich and Berlin?

Comment: Isn't this a subjective question ????

Comment: Purely for the record: my advice, **just go to Munich** and spend more time there.  I always, as a rule, and FWIW, recommend people do less thicker rather than more thinner, travel. You want your Travel to be like lesser full intercourse, rather than morer kissing.

Comment: nicely put, nuts !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided on Nuremberg due to the following reasons:

- I really want to visit Dresden, but it seems to worth more than 6 hours. I think I will lump it with my eventual Budapest-Vienna-Prague trip which is hopefully in 2016.
- Leipzig is near Dresden, so if time is available I can also lump it with my future travel as noted above.
- Bamberg seems to be a quiet town that I like to stroll around, but will bore my wife.
- Nuremberg has toy and railway museum which seems to be interesting.
- It is also the place where the post WW II trial took place so I bet it has more than enough historical value associated with it.
- I need to change train at Nuremberg, so it is a natural stop.
- I won't revisit that area anytime soon.  (Next travel plan is Paris-Low countries, then Budapest-Vienna-Prague).

Answer (score 0):

I've been to Bamberg - very nice medieval town with all the good stuff 5 minutes west of the station.

Also been to Dresden. Things are a lot more spread out and harder to get to in 6 hours.

I have a friend in Leipzig. The town is close enough to Berlin that you can go there on a different day if you really want.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your interest. There are a few things you only get in Nürnberg, others you only get in Leipzig or Bamberg.

If transportation happens to be one of your interests, definitely Nürnberg. And definitely Nürnberg if it is in December (because of the Christmas market).